# Space between Up Navigation and Toolbar title is too large

Tags: android, android-toolbar, up-navigation

Does anyone knows why is it happening?

The first one is how it's look like and the second one is how I want it to look like

[image: That's how it's look like]

[image: That's how I want it to look like]

OBS: When I enable the app icon in the toolbar, it almost has no space between it and the title

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, that happening with everyone using v24.0.0 and above support library version.

Toolbar title has an extra 16dp padding since version 24.0.0 to match material design spec.

All you need to do is set `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`to toolbar view.

Comment: Is there any way to make it get closer??

Comment: you want to make it more closer to up icon even after  setting `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` ? I think you shouldn't do this but in case you want this you can do this by a custom toolbar.