# How to remove padding between upnavigation arrow and Toolbar Title?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, toolbar, android-toolbar

[image]

Top is the default padding for the upnavigation arrow when you set

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

I would like the Toolbar to look more like the bottom image, as I want the title to indicate where the upnavigation arrow will send the user *to* rather than being a description of the current activity. So far I have tried adding a custom textview to the toolbar, and setting `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380934/space-between-up-navigation-and-toolbar-title-is-too-large)  similar question.  But as the author notes, this doesn't remove the padding to the right of the arrow.  How can I get the toolbar to look more like the second image?  Current xml for my toolbar is as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_doc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I further provide the xml for the menu, which I add to the toolbar using the menu inflater.  Another solution I was floating around was adding an arrow icon and textview to the menu itself?  But then I'm not sure how I'd give the new arrow icon the same upnavigation behavior.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24px"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `app:contentInsetStart` to `0dp` instead of `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation`.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
```

Comment: This results in the same spacing as with `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`.  I also tried setting `app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"`